# error while using other model in tensorflow sample "RuntimeException: Node 'output' does not exist in model"

Tags: android, image-processing, tensorflow

Hi I am using Tensorflow in my android application,tensorflow version is 1.2.0. Its working fine with inception model. the application is crashing when I was trying to use other model, I have gone through some other posts
followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43535500/6333830)
but i am getting the following output

```
[u'image_tensor=>Placeholder']
```

MODEL IS : **frozen_inference_graph.pb**