# How to find the Input and Output Nodes of a Frozen Model

Tags: tensorflow, inference, object-detection-api

I want to use tensorflow's `optimize_for_inference.py` script on a frozen Model from the model zoo: the `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco`.

How do i find/determine the names of the input and output name of the model?

[image: Here is a link to the graph generated by tensorboard]

[Hires version of the graph generated by tensorboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDL2V.png)

This question might help: [Given a tensor flow model graph, how to find the input node and output node names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43517959/given-a-tensor-flow-model-graph-how-to-find-the-input-node-and-output-node-name/48209066?noredirect=1#comment83400231_48209066)  (for me it did not)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do using the following code. I downloaded `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco` frozen model from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf1_detection_zoo.md) and was able to get the input and output names as shown below

```
!pip install tensorflow==1.15.5

import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__ # TF1.15.5

gf = tf.GraphDef()  
m_file = open('/content/frozen_inference_graph.pb','rb')
gf.ParseFromString(m_file.read())
 
with open('somefile.txt', 'a') as the_file:
   for n in gf.node:
       the_file.write(n.name+'\n')
 
file = open('somefile.txt','r')
data = file.readlines()
print("output name = ")
print(data[len(data)-1])
 
print("Input name = ")
file.seek ( 0 )
print(file.readline())
```

Output is

```
output name = 
detection_classes

Input name = 
image_tensor
```

Please check the [gist here](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/jvishnuvardhan/bd30545d9a1a773189b6a2cf0ee569f2/untitled.ipynb).

Answer (score 1):

all the models saved using tensorflow object detection api have **image_tensor** as the input node name.
Object detection model has 4 outputs:

1. **num_detections** : Predicts the number of detection for a given image
2. **detection_classes**: Number of classes that the model is trained on
3. **detection_boxes** : predicts (ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax) coordinates
4. **detection_scores** : predicts the confidence for each class, the class which has the highest prediction should be selected

### **code for saved_model inference**

```
def load_image_into_numpy_array(path):
    'Converts Image into numpy array'
    img_data = tf.io.gfile.GFile(path, 'rb').read()
    image = Image.open(BytesIO(img_data))
    im_width, im_height = image.size
    return np.array(image.getdata()).reshape((im_height, im_width, 3)).astype(np.uint8)


# Load saved_model 
model = tf.saved_model.load_model('custom_mode/saved_model',tags=none)

# Convert image into numpy array
numpy_image = load_image_into_numpy_array('Image_path')

# Expand dimensions
input_tensor = np.expand_dims(numpy_image, 0)

# Send image to the model
model_output = model(input_tensor)
# Use output_nodes to predict the outputs 
num_detections = int(model_output.pop('num_detections'))
detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
              for key, value in detections.items()}

detections['num_detections'] = num_detections
detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)
boxes = detections['detection_boxes']
scores = detections['detection_scores']
pred_class = detections['detection_classes']
```

Answer (score -1):

you can just do `model.summary()` to see all the Layer names (and also their type). It is the first column.