# Cannot convert model file to .tflite

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard, tensorflow-lite

I have cloned this [Image Completion](https://github.com/adamstseng/general-deep-image-completion) repository and it works on my windows machine in python. The models for [face-completion](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwBvCjzIsl2vZHoxS0RrRm55d1U/view?usp=sharing) and [general-completion](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwBvCjzIsl2vV3FvZUd0VjdxZE0/view?usp=sharing)
are hosted. However, the files don't have a .pb extension. How can I get the name of input and output tensors? I have tried renaming the files with .pb extension and tried loading in tensorboard using [this article](https://medium.com/@daj/how-to-inspect-a-pre-trained-tensorflow-model-5fd2ee79ced0) but it gives the error shown in the screenshot.

I have also tried running this in python using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43535500/10533299) answer but I get no nodes in output.

How can I get the details like input and output tensors to convert this model into a .tflite model for android? Screenshots:
[import model error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnXs8.png)
[tensorboard error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OetL.png)

Comment: Its possible that the model aren't pb files. How are the files being generated? Are you using the method shown here: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#save_and_restore_models? These methods should automatically save models in the .pb format.

Comment: The model is taken from the repository itself...I don't know how they have generated it. I need to run it on Android so want to convert it to a .tflite model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files provided in the repository are [checkpoints](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#restore_variables), and not `.pb` files that can be converted to `.tflite`. This can be seen from the [`saver.restore()`](https://github.com/adamstseng/general-deep-image-completion/blob/master/face-completion/demo.py#L65) call made in `demo.py`.

To get a pb file, you will have to build a [SavedModel](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#build_and_load_a_savedmodel). The resulting folder will [contain a `.py` file](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#structure_of_a_savedmodel_directory), which you can use for conversion (assuming it contains TFLite-supported ops).

Comment: You are right it seems a checkpoint file. After doing saver.save I got a savedmodel.pb file which I froze using freeze_graph.py. tflite_convert worked on this frozen graph file.