# What are the parameters input_arrays and output_arrays that are needed to convert a frozen model '.pb' file to a '.tflite' file?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite, yolo

I need to convert my `.pb` tensorflow model together with my `.cpkt` file to a `tflite` model to make it work in Mobile Devices. Is there any straight-forward way to find out how can I find what are the parameters I should use for input_arrays and output_arrays?

```
import tensorflow as tf

graph_def_file = "/path/to/Downloads/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224/frozen_graph.pb"
input_arrays = ["input"]
output_arrays = ["MobilenetV1/Predictions/Softmax"]

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(
  graph_def_file, input_arrays, output_arrays)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official docs [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/TFLiteConverter) :

> `input_arrays`: List of input tensors to freeze graph with.
>
> `output_arrays`: List of output tensors to freeze graph with.

Meaning, `input_arrays` is the list of input tensors ( which are mostly placeholder tensors ). `output_arrays` is the list of `Tensor` objects which will act as outputs.

In your case, you are providing the `name` of the `Tensor` object. An actual Tensor object is required.

You can understand it with this example:

```
x1 = tf.placeholder( dtype=tf.float32 )
x2 = tf.placeholder( dtype=tf.float32 )
y = x1 + x2

input_arrays = [ x1 , x2 ]
output_arrays = [ y ]
```

You can learn to find the input and output tensors from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43517959/given-a-tensor-flow-model-graph-how-to-find-the-input-node-and-output-node-name) .
Seeing your code, it seems that you know the tensor names, so you can refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612512/tensorflow-how-to-get-a-tensor-by-name).

Comment: So, you mean I must provide the tensors itself instead if the names? Thanks very much

Comment: Yes. Provide the tensors and not their names. Also, accept the answer if it feels helpful.