# ValueError: Invalid tensors 'outputs' were found when converting from .pb to .tflite

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, quantization, mobilenet

I successfully retrained mobilenet quantized model (`architecture="mobilenet_1.0_128_quantized"`) with my own image dataset:

```
python3 -m scripts.retrain \
  --bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks_quant \
  --how_many_training_steps=50000 \
  --model_dir=tf_files/models/ \
  --summaries_dir=tf_files/training_summaries/"mobilenet_1.0_128_quant" \
  --output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph_50000_1.0_128.pb \
  --output_labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
  --architecture="mobilenet_1.0_128_quantized" \
  --image_dir=images
```

When I try to convert .pb file to .tflite using

```
toco \
  --graph_def_file=tf_files/retrained_graph_50000_1.0_128.pb \
  --output_file=tf_files/retrained_graph_50000_1.0_128.tflite \
  --input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF --output_format=TFLITE \
  --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 \
  --input_shape="1,128,128,3" \
  --input_array=input \
  --output_array=outputs \
  --std_dev_values=127.5 --mean_value=127.5
```

It fails with the next error:

> ValueError: Invalid tensors 'outputs' were found.

Comment: you need to provide output tensor names in `--output_array = ...`

Comment: @kruxx well as you can see I provided it `--output_array=outputs`. I used commands from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/quantize

Comment: Yes! I know the command. But according to your error there is no `ouputs` named tensor in your .pb graph. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43517959/given-a-tensor-flow-model-graph-how-to-find-the-input-node-and-output-node-name) and try to verify your output node name.